# I'm using kivymd and i get this error when I try to import MDDatePicker from kivymd.uix.picker

Tags: python, android, kivymd

**Even though I have already installed kivy and kivymd**

```
 from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
```

**here's the error I get :**

```
In the near future the `FitImage` widget will be moved to the `kivymd.uix.fitimage` package.
Use import of this widget like this:`from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage`.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/media/sf_zed_workflow/Daily_Learning/Side_Projects/to-do/script.py", line 7, in <module>
     from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd.uix.picker'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one-
pip install kivymd,
pip install kivymd